# How to enable Add-Ins in Windows 10 MS Word 365?

Tags: ms-word, office365, ms-office, office-addins

I am creating add-ins for MS Word for the web as well as offline versions.

When I try to publish it into an office store add-ins it works fine on Word for web and for offline.
When I try to add that same "Publish.xml" file in a Word add-ins it doesn't work for me.

For reference, I attached my "Publish.xml" file here.

**Project Type:** Word Web Add-in
**Target Framework:** .Net Framework 4.7.2

Please look into this and give me a response if anyone has an idea on that.

Publish.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Published:70EDFC97-B41D-43C5-B751-7C00AD999804-->
<OfficeApp xsi:type="TaskPaneApp" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides">
  <Id>f5456f09-dc5d-4154-b7ef-3594dce33642</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Deep</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="My Office Add-in" />
  <Description DefaultValue="A task pane add-in for Word" />
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/Images/Button32x32.png" />
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="MyWebSite" />
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain1</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain2</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>AppDomain3</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Document" />
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/Home.html" />
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="Document">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <GetStarted>
            <Title resid="Contoso.GetStarted.Title" />
            <Description resid="Contoso.GetStarted.Description" />
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="Contoso.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" />
          </GetStarted>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabHome">
              <Group id="Contoso.Group1">
                <Label resid="Contoso.Group1Label" />
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
                </Icon>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton">
                  <Label resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Description resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" DefaultValue="https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/Images/Button16x16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" DefaultValue="https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/Images/Button32x32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" DefaultValue="https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/Images/Button80x80.png" />
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/Home.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Contoso.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.Group1Label" DefaultValue="Commands Group" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Get started with your sample add-in!" />
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane" />
        <bt:String id="Contoso.GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Your sample add-in loaded succesfully. Go to the HOME tab and click the 'Show Taskpane' button to get started." />
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```